# How to securely share data between two Flutter apps (credentials)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, authentication

I’m a little bit stuck on a subject.. I was developing 2 mobile applications with Flutter, each with an authentication system. I would like to develop the following functionality:

1. I log on to the "A" application, I save my credentials.
2. I open the "B" app, I can find the account with which I signed in the "A" app. (For example: On my iphone, if I sign in with my google account to Gmail, I find the same account on all the google apps on my phone).

So I would have to be able to store the passwords & identifiers securely on the phone, and only my 2 applications could have access to this "common" database. I looked at Hive/ SQFLITE, but I don’t think it’s suitable for this kind of functionality to share between 2 apps...

Thank you for your help,
JH

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to [Google Account Linking with OAuth-based App Flip](https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking/app-flip-overview):

> OAuth-based App Flip Linking (App Flip) allows your users to easily
> and quickly link their accounts in your authentication system to their
> Google accounts. If your app is installed on your user’s phone when
> they initiate the account linking process, they are seamlessly flipped
> to your app to obtain user authorization.
>
> This approach provides a faster and easier linking process since the
> user does not have to re-enter their username and password to
> authenticate; instead, App Flip leverages the credentials from the
> user's account on your app. Once a user has linked their Google
> account with your app, they can take advantage of any integrations
> that you have developed.

That said, you will need to go Android/iOS-specific to solve this on your own, but you can draw a lot of inspiration from the App Flip example code provided by Google!

On Android you will be using Intents that return data to their caller. The idea would be to have the "A" app listen for a custom intent for example using package [receive_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_intent) that shows some kind of "Allow B to login with A" screen and returns the credentials like this:

```dart
import 'package:receive_intent/receive_intent.dart';
// ...

  Future<void> _setActivityResult() async {
    // ...
    await ReceiveIntent.setResult(kActivityResultOk, data: {"credentials": "abc123"})
  }
// ...
```

Best of luck!